# OpenTok Buttons to control the video

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am trying to build something like below (dribble) using OpenTok JS on the web. The default video elements contain only the mute button. Are there any tutorials/samples or guidance on how to control a video call, add chat, sharing, etc. ?

https://dribbble.com/shots/12215430-Online-Education-Platform-Webinar-page

Another e.g
Looking for pretty much all features on here
https://peercalls.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is the required example, There is video, audio, chat, screen share.

https://github.com/aullman/opentok-meet